# Cypress old error with a path. Splice two pathes into one

Tags: javascript, cypress

Error: Path contains invalid characters: C:\Users\someUser\AppData\Roaming\Cypress\cy\production\projects\config-703c6b3a413d9453b96ab30fb157dca7\bundles\C:\task\shop\ui\main
at checkPath (C:\task\shop\node_modules@cypress\browserify-preprocessor\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\make-dir.js:20:21)

cypress version:  12.8.1

Guys with a Mac os does not have any problems but I with Windows have

Any new ideas how to make workaround for that?

I've found simylar problem with modules and support files:

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2595

but I does no help and one more:

https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/pull/21143

I do not have this fixes in my node_modules